# Node.js vs Javascript Closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I'm working my way through the Eloquent JavaScript Book and in it there is the following code:

```
function createFunction(){
  var local = 100;
  return function(){return local;};
}
```

When I run this via the node console (run node from command prompt) by calling createFunction(), I get [Function] as a returned value. However, according to the book I should get 100.

So my two questions: Why is this? and Second, is running these little examples in the node console a bad idea for testing JS code?

Comment: Steve, nothing other than my second question. Which is what is the best way to run these little examples. I've been using node, can you confirm that that is still a good way to do it? Honestly, I'm not sure how all the pieces fit together. My understanding is that node is the JS engine that's been ripped out of the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the response of `createFunction()`.

```
createFunction()();
```

The first invocation (`()`) calls `createFunction()` and returns the inner function, which the second invocation executes and returns the `local` variable which was closed over.

Running small examples in a node console (or any other) is fine, so long as you know the environment, e.g. a browser's console is generally `eval()`'d, which can create side effects, such as how `delete` can *apparently* delete variables, not just object properties.

Comment: I've never seen this before! Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

You get `100` by invoking the return value of `createFunction`, which is itself a function.

```
createFunction()();
```

...or perhaps more clearly...

```
var new_func = createFunction();

new_func();
```

---

```
function createFunction(){
  var local = 100;

 //  v---v-----------------------v return a function from createFunction
  return function(){return local;};
}

  //  v------- the returned function is assigned to the new_func variable
var new_func = createFunction();

 //   v------- the returned function is invoked
new_func();
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that have a similar problem, I completely missed the double () so the call looks like createFunction()().